# SQL Server insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a simple two-field form that stores its data in the database. For some reason, it isn't working. I have verified that the connection string works, as it is used in another project I made.

I didn't include the beginning of the first class or its page load.

Code:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = txtName.Text;
        string Description = txtSpecial.Text;
        string method = string.Format(
            "INSERT INTO RbSpecials (Name,Description,Active) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','1')",
            Name,
            Description);
        RbConfiguration mySql = new RbConfiguration();
        try
        {
            mySql.Sql_Connection(method);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}

public class RbConfiguration
{
    string DbConnectionString = "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings['RBConnectionString'].ConnectionString";

    public void Sql_Connection(string queryString)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        conn.Open();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the exception appear, and what is it?

Comment: It actually didn't produce an error, when I went to look in the table there was no inserted values. Come to find out, the connection string was enclosed in quotes and I didn't use ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Not answering your question, but your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is very dangerous. Google it up, and start using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well without knowing the error, I'll give it a shot anyway.

```
string DbConnectionString = "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings['RBConnectionString'].ConnectionString";
```

Should be

```
string DbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

And as Adam says, you never actually execute your Query.
The Sql_Connection-method, only opens a connection, and then closes it again, without actually doing anything.

Try this instead:

```
public void Sql_Connection(string queryString)
{
    using( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString) )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh yes you are right. Also I noticed that the name in brackets needs to be in " " not ' '.

Comment: @Nick, ah yes in my haste I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 5):

You never [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) your SQL command:

```
conn.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
conn.Close();
```

And your connection string is wrong (ditch the double quotes):

```
string DbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: thanks, after fixing the connection string and executing the nonquery it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your connection string code must not be a string its class which is getting connection string from web.config, so it should be like this

   string DbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
2. You did not execute your SQlCommand, so will it insert the data, do this

   conn.Open();

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   conn.Close();
3. its not the cause but the best practice to not  to make your code vulnerable to SQLINjection, try this article

[How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)